# Terminal doesn't start after a change to bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I was having an issue with getting VS Code to run `.bashrc` when I launch the integrated terminal (apparently, there has been some recent changes that encourage the use of profiles over shellArgs). Since adding `-l` starts the terminal as a login shell which makes it read `.bash_profile` I made a change to this file by adding `source ~/.bashrc` at the end. So my new bash_profile looked like this:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh'
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then I ran `exec bash` and this immediately froze the terminal!

I used Finder to revert the change and remove the line from the file but the terminal still won't start. Here's a recording of what happens when I start the terminal app from spotlight.

[image: terminal not starting]

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had added `/bin/bash` at the end of `.bashrc` file and this for some reason caused an infinite loop of execution stopping the terminal from starting. As soon as I removed it, the terminal starts normally.

Comment: _for some reason_ : Of curse if you execute bash recursively without breaking the recursion somehow, this will be an infinite recursion (not: infinite loop). This happens always if you write a recursive program and are not careful.....

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'm actually pretty curious as to how this really works, so does it mean that if I run `/bin/bash` it will execute `source ~/.bashrc` again? Cause I believe that's the only way to get into the recursion.

Comment: Read the bash man page: _When an **interactive** shell that is **not a login** shell is started, bash reads and  executes  commands  from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists._. You can turn off that behaviour by running `bash --norc`.